# Oracle SQL trigger after insert, update table with corresponding columns

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my code for creating the trigger update table with corresponding columns

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_trig after insert ON TR
FOR EACH ROW
 
  UPDATE IT 
  SET ODNUM = TR.ODNUM,
  SET INEM = TR.INEM, 
  SET QTS = TR.QTS,
  SET PR = TR.PR,
  WHERE IT.ORNUM = TR.ORDNUM
```

Comment: You have more than one issue. I would start from [how to create a trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from zillion *stupid* errors, such as

- typos

  - "price" vs. "prince"
  - "received" vs. "recieved"
  - "ordern0" (with zero at the end) vs. "orderno"
- superfluous `set` keywords
- missing statement terminator
- missing `end`

the rest is "OK"; I mean, trigger compiles.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trans_trig AFTER
  2    INSERT ON transactions
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    UPDATE orders
  6    SET orderno = :new.orderno,
  7        cno = :new.cno,
  8        sno = :new.sno,
  9        received = :new.received,
 10        shipped = NULL, --:new.SHIPPED,
 11        type = :new.type
 12    WHERE orderno = :new.orderno;
 13
 14    UPDATE items
 15    SET orderno = :new.orderno,
 16        itemno = :new.itemno,
 17        quantity = :new.quantity,
 18        prince = :new.prince
 19    WHERE items.orderno = :new.orderno;
 20
 21  END;
 22  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

I suggest you be more careful as majority of errors could have been avoided, only if you paid attention. Another part is easily fixed by following basic syntax.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know who wrote what, but it is **you** who asked the question here, on Stack Overflow, so I find **you** responsible for the contents.